# Is there a way to delete all rows matching a regex in a table in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

Assume I have the below table:

```
#   North South
1   17     55
2   19     66
3   28     77
4   26     88
5   35     99
6   32     44
7   42     33
```

Assuming I want to delete all rows containing the digit ‘4’, that would be rows 6 and 7. Is there a way to do this in javascript?

I want something like below:

```
regex = ‘%4%’;
var table = document.getElementById('Table');
for (var i=0;i < table.rows.length;i++){
 if (table.rows[i] has regex)
    table.row[i]. delete
}
```

Any you in advance for the help

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```js
var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
for (var i = table.rows.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    if (table.rows[i].textContent.indexOf('4') !== -1){
        table.rows[i].remove();
    }
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td>123</td><td>456</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="some4">789</td><td>012</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>345</td><td>678</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Notice how this only removes cells that contain "4", and leaves rows that have the search strings in their attributes intact.

Please note that [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) is IE 9+.

Comment: This will fail if you have two consecutive rows with `4` in them. If you delete row `1`, then increment `i` to `2`, the row that *was* in position `2` will never be checked. Visit the rows in reverse order to avoid this problem (`for (var i = table.rows.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)`)